# Error in installing c# application in database

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008

I have a windows application in C#, my connection string is:

and my database is in SQL Server 2008 R2.
but when I installed my program I receive This error:
[image]

Please help me I don't know how to solve this

Comment: Change the name of your project

Comment: Are you creating Database?

Comment: No,database is in my debug file, I want to attach it to client's database

Comment: Why should I change the name of the project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I guessed, you are (attaching is) **creating**  a new database.

You are facing this problem because there is already a database in that server with the same Db name and primary file name. This is probably (mostly) due to adding the Db twice.

Please open [SQL-Server Management Studio](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174173.aspx), and check the already existing Db of name `IcuProject`. If it's the same Db that you wanted to attach, then skip attaching part or delete the current db from server and try attaching it again.

As a best practice, if you are attaching a db thru application, then make sure that no db with same name already exists in the server. or best, ask user to enter a Db name so that you won't get a name conflict.

Comment: Can I write a connection String that at the first time attaches the database in client SQL Server and after that not to do that.

Comment: Yea. You can. Actually, that is how you are supposed to write.

Comment: Are you trying copy-paste something? If so, its not working.

Comment: My connection String is:    <add name="ConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS; Initial Catalog=IcuProject;Integrated Security=True;AttachDbFileName=|datadirectory|\IcuProject.mdf;"
            providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"
             />                                                                                                                  how can I correct that?

Comment: This method is wrong. Never attach a DB like this. Create different query and attach the db if only that particular db does not exist.

Comment: If the answer has helped you, please check it as right answer. This will help other users to identify quickly.